# How can I use javascript to load and submit a website's AJAX form and display the results?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, keyword-search

Specifically, I would like to create a Firefox keyword search for Baidu Maps. if I right-click the search form to create a keyword search, the keyword search's URL is saved as http://ditu.baidu.com/?word=%s&ft=tab  , but if I replace the %s with e.g. "shanghai", just the start page loads, whereas if I directly type "shanghai" into the search field, search results will be displayed. So I think I'll probably need to use javascript to load the start page, submit my search query and load the results. How would I do that?

I tried typing this in the location bar:

```
javascript:location.replace('http://ditu.baidu.com/');Instance('TANGRAM_28').searchWord('人民路');
```

However it only loads the website without submitting the query.
So after the page has loaded I can type in the part after the semicolon into the location bar:

```
javascript:Instance('TANGRAM_28').searchWord('人民路');
```

and the query results are displayed with a red A. How can I load the page and submit the query just by typing one line into the location bar?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: You probably need to send a POST request, or use a different URL.

Comment: @francisco.preller Thanks for pointing that out, I hope it's clearer now.